How to remove events from Workflow Library
While coding, I added some events to my workflow library, and now I cant delete them. Whats more is that I cant make custom workflows any more because I keep getting an error like this
Function Name must have a value in Workflow Step: Workflow Code=MS-EDOCTOS-01, ID=536. It cannot be zero or empty.

This is just an example of what happens when I try to add a step, even to the default/template workflows that Business Central provides you with.
codeunit 50138 "Custom Workflow Mgmt"
{


    procedure CheckApprovalsWorkflowEnabled(var RecRef: RecordRef): Boolean
    begin
        if not WorkflowMgmt.CanExecuteWorkflow(RecRef, GetWorkflowCode(RUNWORKFLOWONSENDFORAPPROVALCODE, RecRef)) then
            Error(NoWorkflowEnabledErr);
        exit(true);
    end;

    procedure GetWorkflowCode(WorkflowCode: code[128]; RecRef: RecordRef): Code[128]
    begin
        exit(DelChr(StrSubstNo(WorkflowCode, RecRef.Name), '=', ''));
    end;


    [IntegrationEvent(false, false)]
    procedure OnSendWorkflowForApproval(var RecRef: RecordRef)
    begin

    end;

    [IntegrationEvent(false, false)]
    procedure OnCancelWorkflowForApproval(var RecRef: RecordRef)
    begin

    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Workflow Event Handling", 'OnAddWorkflowEventsToLibrary', '', false, false)]
    local procedure OnAddWorkflowEventsToLibrary()
    var
        RecRef: RecordRef;
        WorkflowMgmt: Codeunit "Workflow Event Handling";
    begin
        RecRef.Open(Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table);
        WorkflowMgmt.AddEventToLibrary(GetWorkflowCode(RUNWORKFLOWONSENDFORAPPROVALCODE, RecRef), Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table,
          GetWorkflowEventDesc(WorkflowSendForApprovalEventDescTxt, RecRef), 0, false);
        WorkflowMgmt.AddEventToLibrary(GetWorkflowCode(RUNWORKFLOWONCANCELFORAPPROVALCODE, RecRef), DATABASE::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table,
          GetWorkflowEventDesc(WorkflowSendForCancelEventDescTxt, RecRef), 0, false);
        WorkflowMgmt.AddEventToLibrary(GetWorkflowCode(RUNWORKFLOWONCANCELFORAPPROVALCODE, RecRef), DATABASE::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table,
        GetWorkflowEventDesc(RunWorkflowApprovedDescTxt, RecRef), 0, false);
    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Custom Workflow Mgmt", 'OnSendWorkflowForApproval', '', false, false)]
    local procedure RunWorkflowOnSendWorkflowForApproval(var RecRef: RecordRef)
    begin
        WorkflowMgmt.HandleEvent(GetWorkflowCode(RUNWORKFLOWONSENDFORAPPROVALCODE, RecRef), RecRef);
    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Custom Workflow Mgmt", 'OnCancelWorkflowForApproval', '', false, false)]
    local procedure RunWorkflowOnCancelWorkflowForApproval(var RecRef: RecordRef)
    begin
        WorkflowMgmt.HandleEvent(GetWorkflowCode(RUNWORKFLOWONCANCELFORAPPROVALCODE, RecRef), RecRef);
    end;


    procedure GetWorkflowEventDesc(WorkflowEventDesc: code[128]; RecRef: RecordRef): Text
    begin
        exit(StrSubstNo(WorkflowEventDesc, RecRef.Name));
    end;


    //handle document

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Workflow Response Handling", 'OnOpenDocument', '', false, false)]
    local procedure OnOpenDocument(RecRef: RecordRef; var Handled: Boolean)
    var
        rec: Record PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table;
    begin
        case RecRef.Number of
            Database::"PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table":
                begin
                    RecRef.SetTable(rec);
                    rec.Validate(ApprovalStatus, rec.ApprovalStatus::Open);
                    rec.Modify();
                    Handled := true;
                end;
        end;
    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Approvals Mgmt.", 'OnSetStatusToPendingApproval', '', false, false)]
    local procedure OnSetStatusToPendingApproval(RecRef: RecordRef; var Variant: Variant; var IsHandled: Boolean)
    var
        rec: Record PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table;
    begin
        case RecRef.Number of
            Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table:
                begin
                    RecRef.SetTable(rec);
                    rec.Validate(ApprovalStatus, rec.ApprovalStatus::Pending);
                    rec.Modify(true);
                    Variant := rec;
                    IsHandled := true;
                end;
        end;
    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Approvals Mgmt.", 'OnPopulateApprovalEntryArgument', '', false, false)]
    local procedure OnPopulateApprovalEntryArgument(var RecRef: RecordRef; var ApprovalEntryArgument: Record "Approval Entry"; WorkflowStepInstance: Record "Workflow Step Instance")
    var
        rec: Record PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table;
    begin

        case RecRef.Number of
            Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table:
                begin
                    RecRef.SetTable(rec);
                    ApprovalEntryArgument."Document No." := rec."Lot No.";
                end;
        end;


    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Workflow Response Handling", 'onReleaseDocument', '', false, false)]
    local procedure onReleaseDocument(RecRef: RecordRef; var Handled: Boolean)
    var
        finalReportTemp: Record FinalReportTable temporary;
        finalReport: Record FinalReportTable;
        assayRecord: Record PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table;
        myNotification: Notification;
    begin
        case RecRef.Number of
            Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table:
                begin
                    RecRef.SetTable(assayRecord);
                    assayRecord.Validate(ApprovalStatus, assayRecord.ApprovalStatus::Approved);
                    assayRecord.Modify(true);

                    if not finalReport.Get(assayRecord.ID) then begin
                        finalReport.Reset();
                        assayRecord.SetRange(ID, assayRecord.ID);
                        if assayRecord.FindFirst() then begin
                            finalReportTemp.ID := assayRecord.ID;
                            finalReportTemp."Lot No." := assayRecord."Lot No.";
                            finalReportTemp."Client Name" := assayRecord."Client Name.";
                            finalReportTemp.Notes := assayRecord.Notes;
                            finalReportTemp.AssayTotal := assayRecord.Weight1 + assayRecord.Weight2 + assayRecord.Weight3;
                            finalReportTemp.ProofAssay := assayRecord.WeightProof;
                            finalReport."Lot Weight" := assayRecord."Lot Weight";
                            finalReport := finalReportTemp;
                            finalReport.Insert();
                            Commit();


                        end;

                    end;

                    Handled := true;
                end;
        end;
    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Approvals Mgmt.", 'onRejectApprovalRequest', '', false, false)]
    local procedure onRejectApprovalRequest(var ApprovalEntry: Record "Approval Entry")
    var
        RecRef: RecordRef;
        rec: Record PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table;
    begin
        case ApprovalEntry."Table ID" of
            Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table:
                begin
                    if rec.Get(ApprovalEntry."Document No.") then begin
                        rec.Validate(rec.ApprovalStatus, rec.ApprovalStatus::Closed);
                        rec.Modify(true);
                    end;
                end;
        end;
    end;

    [EventSubscriber(ObjectType::Codeunit, Codeunit::"Approvals Mgmt.", 'OnApproveApprovalRequest', '', false, false)]
    local procedure OnApproveApprovalRequest(var ApprovalEntry: Record "Approval Entry")
    var
        RecRef: RecordRef;
        rec: Record PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table;
    begin
        case ApprovalEntry."Table ID" of
            Database::PostedPrelimaryAssay1Table:
                begin
                    if rec.Get(ApprovalEntry."Document No.") then begin
                        rec.Validate(rec.ApprovalStatus, rec.ApprovalStatus::Approved);
                        rec.Modify(true);
                    end;
                end;
        end;
    end;

    var
        WorkflowMgmt: Codeunit "Workflow Management";
        RUNWORKFLOWONSENDFORAPPROVALCODE: label 'RUNWORKFLOWONSEND%1FORAPPROVAL';
        RUNWORKFLOWONCANCELFORAPPROVALCODE: label 'RUNWORKFLOWONCANCEL%1FORAPPROVAL';
        RUNWORKFLOWAPPROVEDCODE: label 'RUNWORKFLOWAPPROVEDCODE';
        NoWorkflowEnabledErr: Label 'No approval workflow for this record type is enabled';

        WorkflowSendForApprovalEventDescTxt: Label 'Approval of %1 is requested';
        WorkflowSendForCancelEventDescTxt: Label 'Approval of %1 is canceled';
        RunWorkflowApprovedDescTxt: Label '%1 is approved';



}

This is the workflow management code

